# how to set unchanging transparency on a random hex color generator

Tags: javascript, random, colors, hex

I'm working on programming a screen saver, coding in javaScript, and I want the lines that are drawn to be solid enough to be seen but transparent enough you can see a pattern emerge as it continues to draw I've got a random color generator working with hex colors and I've been trying to figure out how to set the transparency so that it isn't random but everything else is. is this possible? if so how?

here's what I've got as far as color generation...

```
function getRandomColor() 
{
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  {
     color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

  }  
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)`:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var trans = '0.5'; // 50% transparency
  var color = 'rgba(';
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',';
  }
  color += trans + ')'; // add the transparency
  return color;
}

var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
document.getElementById('cc').onclick=function(){
  h1.style.color = getRandomColor();
};
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Hello, World!</h1>
<button id="cc">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: Thank you I feel kinda dumb now as I tried that but assumed I was wrong as I placed the alpha channel? at the wrong end of the color code thank you.

Comment: @Jonny09 Glad that helped :).

Comment: ummm....so admitedly shoulf have tried it before initaly comenting but....rather than semi-transparent random colors all its putting out is semitransparent white....

Comment: so basicly if i want to change the transparency the bast way is to use rgba?

Comment: @Jonny09 Yes, `rgba(r, g, b, a)` is the best way. You also could avoid hex codes as in my last edit.

Comment: Glad to've helped :).

Answer (score 0):

You could use rgba instead of hex.

Something like this:

```
function getRandomValue(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
     return Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0; //Don't know how random works
  }  
}


function getRandomColor() 
{
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = 'rgba';
  color += `(${getRandomValue()},${getRandomValue()},${getRandomValue()}`;
  return color;
}
```

Or try using opacity in CSS